# Change process value from codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, percentage

I use ASP.NET

I want to show percentage to user from codebehind while database working .

I think problem is here,when i call this function from cs percentege WORKS FINE!

```
  protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
  }
```

But my real code is connect a database and insert 300 - 1000 rows !!
When it works server cursor icon changed to busy icon,so it frozen and i cant set my percentage value.

Plz Help...

I got a webservice :

```
    public double CommittedCount = 0;

    [WebMethod]
    public string ShowPercentage()
    {
        return ((CommittedCount / FinishCount) * 100 ).ToString();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void SetCommittedCount(double committedCount)
    {
        CommittedCount = committedCount;
    }


    public double FinishCount
    {
        get
        {
                if(Glob.ExcelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    return Glob.ExcelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                return 1;

        }
    }
```

I got an ajaxcall function:

```
function updateProgress() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/processCalculator.asmx/ShowPercentage") %>',
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (msg) {
                // TODO: revert the line below in your actual code
                //$("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", msg.d);
                $(".percentage").text(msg.d);
                if (msg.d < 100) {
                    setTimeout(updateProgress, 100);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

I called updateProgress button onclick:

```
<asp:Button Text="Sorgula" ID="btnAction" class="button_action" OnClick="Action_Click" Width="80px" runat="server" />

        $(".button_action").click(function () {
            var action_ = $(this).attr("value");
            var ExcelRowCount = $('#<%=ExcelActionsIsAvaibleRowCount.ClientID %>').val();
            if (ExcelRowCount != "") {
                if (confirm(ExcelRowCount + " kayıt için [" + action_ + "] aksiyonu gerçekleştirilecek?")) {
                    setTimeout(updateProgress, 100);
                    return true;
                }
                else 
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

My Cs Action Code
    protected void btnAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

```
...
...
for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < Glob.ExcelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
{
   ...     
   ...                

   aksiyon_sonucu_ = action.InsertRow(
   Glob.ExcelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowIndex], DegistirilebilirKolonlar, true);

  // my persentage
  processCalculater pCal = new processCalculater();
  pCal.SetCommittedCount(rowIndex);

  ...
  ...
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use PageAsyncTask (or some other multithreading).

Here's the article on usage from MSDN, which also has an example that shows a progress indicator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pageasynctask.aspx

Other options for multithreading are:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000))
```

and

```
new Thread(() => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)){ IsBackground = true }.Start()
```

The idea is to put your long running task into a background thread (using any of the techniques above).  Pass in your context (session) to save your progress.  Then using AJAX and a WebMethod, you can access the session data and show the progress of the background thread.

Comment: How i can call more this PageAsyncTask  ? Its only one call i couldnt figure it.I want to call this every second how can i do this ?

Comment: You don't want to call PageAsyncTask every second, just once. See the added notes in my answer.

Comment: How do i stop this thread ? new Thread(() => w.ActionStart(ac)) { IsBackground = true }.Start();

Comment: @Mennan - Read this article about starting and terminating thread.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.80).aspx